# PL/SQL Cursor is not displaying the results

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, cursor

I'm very new to PL/SQL programming. I have a table named `course`. When I do:

```
select * from course where branchid = 'B1';
```

it returns the results as below:

[image]

And here is the PL/SQL programs I try to run against this table:

```
declare 
    v_branchId course.branchid%TYPE := 'B1';
    cursor course_cur is
    select * from course where branchid = v_branchId;

    v_cursor course_cur%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    open course_cur;
    LOOP
        FETCH course_cur into v_cursor;
        exit when course_cur%NOTFOUND;

        dbms_output.put_line('The course id is  ' || v_cursor.courseid );

    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

The program is been executed successfully, but it never prints the `courseid`'s at all, even though for branchid `B1` I have several `courseid`'s.

Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you given `SET SERVEROUT ON` command before executing the PL/SQL Block

Answer (score 1):

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited
```

to get started. Check also wrapping option if needed. 

 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG099

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this and let me know the result :)

```
declare 

cursor course_cur (v_branchId in varchar2) is
select * from course where branchid = v_branchId;

v_cursor course_cur%ROWTYPE;
```

BEGIN

```
open course_cur ('B1');
LOOP
    FETCH course_cur into v_cursor;
    exit when course_cur%NOTFOUND;

    dbms_output.put_line('The course id is  ' || v_cursor.courseid );

END LOOP;
```

END;

thanks